How Does .venv in Python Inherit Jupyter Notebook from System?
Context
I was not a regular virtual environment user. I just used to install pip packages at the user level like
python3 -m pip install --user tensorflow

and worked with it. This is how installed my jupyter lab as well to work with ipython notebooks.
But only recently, I got into the habit of installing pip packages on a project level by creating virtual environments like
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv)$ python3 -m pip install tensorflow # Within the virtual environment, example

Question
Even within the virtual environment, whenever I run
(.venv) $ jupyter notebook

it fires up, without having to explicitly install jupyter within the environment. So it almost looks like somehow jupyter is inheriting from my user level packages. But, within the environment, when I try these
(.venv) $ python3 -m pip freeze # Empty, no package
(.venv) $ python3
>>> import tensorflow # Module not found, as tf exists only in the base environment

So, what's the deal here? If the .venv is providing a true isolation from the base (as tensorflow does not seem to inherit from the base), how come it inherits jupyter?
Platform (if Relevant)
Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.

When you run jupyter the shell looks it up in the $PATH. Activated virtual environment prepends its .venv/bin to $PATH (that's actually almost all what .venv/bin/activate does, everything else is implemented inside Python interpreter). If jupyter is not found in the current virtual env shell searches it in other directories. Once found shell executes it. Nothing fancy here.
The more fancy part is: jupyter is a script with a shebang so it runs a Python interpreter different from the current virtual env and that Python interpreter imports modules from a different site-packages. That explains, I hope.
To find out where jupyter is:
which jupyter

To find out its shebang:
head -1 `which jupyter`


Does it mean, if the same package (e. g. tensorflow) is absent in venv, but present in the base environment, then it will still be visible from venv? From what you say, it seems like venv looks at its own path first (inside the project directory) only then it goes looking at the user level.
Ideally, I wish venv would not look at anything system level at all, to provide true isolation. Do I have to use something like poetry for that? Or need to go full docker container?

@Della No. You run jupyter as a script — it's available in $PATH and is being ran under different (from the current venv) python. Importable package absent in the currently activated venv are not available for the python from venv/bin. Difference between scripts and libraries, see? To make sure you run a script only from the venv run venv/bin/jupyter or venv/bin/python venv/bin/jupyter or (if the library provides the way) python -m jupyter; this way you're sure you run python only from the current venv.
